# Kotlin Moshi Adapter not called

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I'm trying to write a Moshi adapter in Kotlin that will create enums based on an integer value, and will also default to a specific enum value if it encounters an unsupported value.

My adapter is never getting called, which causes the default enum adapter to fail with the included stacktrace.

Tracing the code show that the `@ToJson` annotation somehow isn't present, and so the adapter [isn't added when it should be](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/AdapterMethodsFactory.java#L111).

Declaring the adapter

```
enum class Status {
    IDLE,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    FAILED,
    SUCCESS,
    UNKNOWN;

    companion object {
        private val map = Status.values().associateBy(Status::ordinal);
        fun fromInt(type: Int?): Status {
            var ret = map[type]
            if (ret == null) {
                ret = UNKNOWN
            }
            return ret
        }

    }

    class Adapter {
        @ToJson
        fun toJson(status: Status): Int {
            return status.ordinal
        }

        @FromJson
        fun fromJson(value: Int): Status {
            return fromInt(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Building Moshi

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi.Builder()
            .add(Status.Adapter())
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
}
```

Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.6.0'
```

Stacktrace

```
05-29 18:57:56.603 24560-24560/com.example.app E/MyActivity: com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected one of [IDLE, IN_PROGRESS, FAILED, SUCCESS, UNKNOWN] but was 2 at path $[0].status
    at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$EnumJsonAdapter.fromJson(StandardJsonAdapters.java:297)
    at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$EnumJsonAdapter.fromJson(StandardJsonAdapters.java:266)
    at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$2.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:137)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$FieldBinding.read(ClassJsonAdapter.java:196)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter.fromJson(ClassJsonAdapter.java:158)
    at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$2.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:137)
    at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.fromJson(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:76)
    at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$2.fromJson(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:53)
    at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$2.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:137)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:45)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
    ...
```

Comment: I couldn’t reproduce this. https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/e556b6e6687d31536f8a58eb0039eda2

Comment: Did you tell your Retrofit instance about your Moshi instance? https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/moshi

Comment: Thanks so much Jesse. Your hunch was correct. I failed to pass my `Moshi` instance into my `MoshiConverterFactory`. Thanks for the help!